# SQL SELECT statement when using look up table

Tags: sql, sql-server

sorry if I'm not framing this question properly but I'm very new to `SQL` statements and I can't seem to get this right I need help working out how to do a `SELECT` statement with a **lookup** table involved, there's the situation:

```
Employee table
[ID], [Name], [StartDate]

User_Roles (lookup) table
[Employee_ID], [Role_ID]

Roles Table
[Id], [RoleName]
```

So, from what I can see the `employee` has an **ID, Name, and StartDate,**

the `User_Roles` table assigns a **role ID to the user ID** and

the `Roles Table` has the **Roles Codes**.

I needed a **Select statement** that returns:

```
Employee.ID, Employee.Name, Employee.StartDate, Roles.RoleName
```

Based on what the mapping is in the `User_Roles` table.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you could start by reading this http://etutorials.org/SQL/Mastering+Oracle+SQL/Chapter+3.+Joins/3.3+Types+of+Joins/

Comment: Thank you guys, Bartdude I only got as far as selecting everything, I tried Joins but I am just too new to figure this. thank you fGo, incredibly helpful link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use multiple joins to work across the relationships.

```
select e.id, e.name, e.startDate, r.RoleName 
from employee e 
join user_roles ur
on e.id = ur.employee_id
join roles r
on r.id = ur.role_id
```

**Full Example**

```
/*DDL*/

create table EMPLOYEE(
   ID int,
   Name varchar(50),
   StartDate date
);

create table USER_ROLES(
  Employee_ID int,
  Role_ID int
);

create table Roles(
  ID int,
  RoleName varchar(50)
);

insert into EMPLOYEE values(1, 'Jon Skeet', '2013-03-04');
insert into USER_ROLES values (1,1);
insert into ROLES values(1, 'Superman');

/* Query */
select e.id, e.name, e.startDate, r.RoleName 
from employee e 
join user_roles ur
on e.id = ur.employee_id
join roles r
on r.id = ur.role_id;
```

**[Working Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc1d/1)**

[Nice Article Explaining Joins](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-join-three-tables-in-sql-query-mysql-sqlserver.html)

Comment: Looking at this now thank you Kevin, I will post as answer if it works

Comment: Thanks Phil, I'm not sure the flavor of your DB but the SQL Fiddle uses MySql

Comment: Thanks Kevin I learnt an awful lot from that. truly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT e.ID, e.Name, e.StartDate, r.RoleName
FROM Employee as e
INNER JOIN UserRoles as ur on ur.EmployeeID = e.ID 
INNER JOIN Roles as r on ur.Role_ID = r.Id
```

Please note that you will get several rows per employee if the employee has more than one role.